# Is unintentional orgasm a sin?

Tags: sin

From some day , I suddenly get a dirty thought I fight with that thought and then try to keep still but I do not know what was wrong with me it was my asr Salah time my wudu break 3 time and than I went to washroom and all of sudden my penis ejaculated I have no intention for that , I had an thought but I somehow controlled it have I done a sin ? I was addicted to mans*** and porno*** but alhamdulillah due to Allah help it is been almost 3-4 months  I have not done them so is this type of ejaculation.a sin ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An unintentional orgasm is comparable to a wet dream.  IslamWeb addresses this topic:

> If the questioner is asking whether or not it is forbidden to have a wet dream while asleep, then **the answer is no because the sperm comes out unintentionally**.
>   <sub>[IslamWeb](http://www.islamweb.net/emainpage/index.php?page=showfatwa&Option=FatwaId&Id=88923)</sub>

A relevant hadith is:

> ... Actions are to be judged only by intentions and a man will have only what he intended. ...
>   [Sunan Abi Dawud 2201](https://sunnah.com/abudawud/13/27)

You'll need to to use your own judgment to decide if it's unintentional or not.

[SeekersHub](http://seekershub.org/ans-blog/2013/02/26/rules-regarding-ghusl-and-wet-dreams-for-men-and-women/) discusses the need to perform ghusl after a wet dream (and this would likewise apply here):

> So, if a man or woman has a wet dream and he/she sees wetness/discharge they are obliged to make ghusl ...