# Mastubration by accident

Tags: halal-haram, masturbation

Some days ago when I was sleeping after me and my husband had sex and my hand was on my vagina (I was not wearing pants) so I was unconscious like I was really sleepy and I did not know what I was doing so my hand touched my clitoris so I felt a good feeling and continued so I started to rub it till I felt my bed and hands were wet because I had mastubrated so I asked my husband if it was haram but he did not know the answer. So please tell me if it is punishable or what I did was haram. Please don’t take me in a bad way

Comment: I wonder if what you described is what is considered an accident or an unintentional act.

Comment: Related: [Is unintentional orgasm a sin?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/46357/17163)

Answer (score -3):

It is totally haram in islam it is related to zina especially to unmarried person please  avoid  this great sin

Touching to any private  with bad intentions is also great sin but not during sexual intercourse with partner

[image]/874mB.jpg

Comment: Pictures are not searchable. If you copy and paste the text into your answer, this would be better.